# Confusions about participles

Tags: grammaire, participe-passé, participe-présent

In *Bescherelle, La grammaire*, it reads that

> le **participe passé**, comme temps composé, indique l'aspect accompli. Son action est généralement antérieure à l'action du verbe conjugué. e.g. Ses amis *étant partis*, elle se sent soudain très seule. Ses amis *étant partis*, elle se sentira bien seule.

But in general, does past participle imply some sense of past tense? It seems more likely to convey a sense of passive voice, just like in English.

And it separates participles from verbal adjectives. It reads that

> (Le participe présent) conserve les propriétés du verbe. e.g. C'est un incident *n'entraînant* aucune conséquence grave.
>
> (L'adjectif verbal) ne conserve pas les propriétés du verbe. e.g. Il nous a joué un air *entraînant*. On ne peut pas dire: il nous a joué un air n'entraînant pas.

It's pretty confusing since I cannot figure out the difference between these two usages of *entraînant*. The same for past participles:

> (Épithète) J'ai visité un village entièrement *construit* sur pilotis.
>
> (L'adjectif verbal) n'admet pas de négation verbale: La presse *écrite* est en difficulté. On ne peut pas dire: La presse n'étant pas écrite est en difficulté.

Therefore I'm pretty confused about the usage of participles. I need your help to clarify these confusions. Thanks!

## EDIT:

One of the answer(s) claims that the past participle is actually passive participle for transitive verbs. On *Bescherelle, La grammaire*, it reads that

> Le participe passé peut prendre deux formes différentes.
>
> - La **forme simple** est constituée du participe passé sans auxiliaire exprimé. *charmé*, *guéri*, *sorti*, *vendu*
> - La **forme composée** est constituée de l'auxiliaire *avoir* ou *être* au participe présent suivi du **participe passé**. *paniquer*->*ayant paniqué*; *sortir*->*étant sorti*.

So for transitive verbs, the first one is passive and the second one is active? And only the second one conveys a sense of accomplishment when it's used as «épithète»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alors il faut d'abord faire la différence entre deux usages du participe:

- le participe-adjectif
- le participe-proposition

Le **participe-adjectif** s'utilise comme un adjectif, il a deux formes:

- actif (`ravissant`=*pretty*)
- passif (`ravi`=*happy*, both from `ravir`=*give joy*)

Il s'accorde avec le nom: `une personne ravissante`, `des hommes ravis`. On peut le remplacer par une proposition commençant par `qui...`: `un endroit charmant`=`un endroit qui charme`, `une fête réussie`=`une fête qui est réussie`. Il n'a aucune notion de temps: `une fête réussie` peut être réussie demain ou hier! La négation se construit comme avec les adjectifs avec `non-`, `in-`, `peu`, etc. : `construit` => `non-construit`, `intéressant` => `inintéressant`, `ravissant` => `peu ravissant`.

Souvent le participe-adjectif prend un sens particulier du verbe: `charmant`=*charming* (alors que charmer=*seduce*), `entraînant`=*gay* (alors que `entraîner`=*cause*), etc.

Le **participe-proposition**, lui, a 4 formes:

- présent actif:  `ravissant`
- présent passif: `étant ravi`, souvent abrégé `ravi`
- passé actif:    `ayant ravi`
- passé passif:   `ayant été ravi`, souvent abrégé `ravi`

Il s'agit d'un vrai verbe, avec un sujet et, dans le cas des verbes transitifs, un complément. On peut toujours le remplacer par un verbe sous une autre forme: `L'actrice, attirant chaque jour davantage de spectateurs, doit trouver une nouvelle salle pour accueillir son public.` = `L'actrice, parce qu'elle attire chaque jour...`.

Le participe-proposition est invariable (`L'actrice, attirant...` vs. `L'acteur, attirant...`). Le sens est différent du participe-adjectif: `une actrice attirante` = *an attractive actress* vs. `L'actrice, attirant...`=*The actress, attracting more and more people...*. Le participe a des complément: `une actrice attirant les foules`, `une fête ayant réussi à améliorer l'ambiance`. La négation est `ne ... pas`, comme les verbes: `Ne criant pas victoire, il gardait son calme.` (adj. `criant`=*obvious*, cf. `un bonheur criant`, `une joie criante`).

Bien sût, il y a des cas ambigus: `une maison construite en bois`=`... ayant été construite en bois`. C'est une proposition ou un adjectif? Et `un discours construit`(=*structured*)? On a souvent la réponse en mettant au négatif: `une maison qui n'est pas construite en bois` (=> proposition), `un discours peu construit` (=> adjectif), mais la frontière est pas toujours claire.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem very confused. The so-called past participle is actually a passive participle for transitive verbs (hence its agreement with the direct object) and an adjectival form not taking any clitic complements (*me, te, se, ..., le, la, les, lui, leur, y, en*) or negation (*ne*).

The present participle is a verbal form: it does not agree with anything in gender or number and takes clitic complements. The verbal adjective is actually an adjective agreeing in gender and number with the noun it modifies.

Comment: For the present participle: how to distinguish it with verbal adjective even if there's no evidence of agreement just like the example given in the question where both are written as «entraînant» in the same form?

Comment: Edited for so-called passive participles.

Comment: For the present participle, it seems that the presence of a complement is obligatory hence marking the difference with the converted adjective.

Comment: Or rather that the use of the present participle is obligatory if you want to use a verbal complement...